# System.String[] - Result

Tags: powershell

I did a search and I understand the issue that some of these are arrays.  What I am not sure I understand is why I am getting this when I am specifically trying to return just one value.

I am using a ForEach loop and pulling from a text file the names of the computers I want to query.
I want to verify that the IP address I am pinging is the same computer I want to connect to.  We have many users on VPN and the DNS doesn't update fast enough.  This means we get some incorrect information.

```
$NIC2 = Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object {$_.DNSDomain -eq "usms.contoso.com"} | Select-Object IPAddress
```

This should give me only one IP address and not an array, but unfortunately I get the System.String[] in the CSV output.  If I just type this command out in the PowerShell command line it works beautifully, but not when I put it into a CSV.

any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Entire code below - I get the results for everything except the $NIC2 and doing $NIC2.IPAddress[0] doesn't seem to work.

Putting $NIC2[0] just give me this in that column
dapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object {$_.DNSDomain -eq "contoso.com"} | Select-Object IPAddress

```
#Definitions of variables
#************************
    #Defines the location and name of the text file from where computers will be pulled
    $Computers = Get-Content "c:\Temp\computers.txt"  

    #Defines the variable and format for Date
    $Date = Get-date -UFormat %h_%d_%y_%H%M

    #Define the name of the files to output
    $OutputFile = "C:\Temp\Verify-Computer-$Date.csv" #All Computers On-Line Status will be provided in this file

  
    #Defines the Array where to put the data and the $Ping variable to store the IP address
    $DataArray = @()
    $Resolution = New-Object System.Object.NetworkInformation.Ping

#Define A Function that will test which computers are on-line and create files to use in the other function.
ForEach ($computer in $Computers) 
{

#Defining the variables
$TESTConnection = $null
$Object = $null
$Value = $null
$IPAddress = $null
$NameResolution = $null
$PingAddress = $null
$NIC = $null
$NIC2 = $null
$NICIP = $null



# Ping computer
$TESTConnection = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object PingSucceeded 

    #If connection is live Get IP address
    IF ($TESTConnection.PingSucceeded -eq "True") {

        $IPAddress = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $computer -InformationLevel "Detailed" | Select-Object RemoteAddress
        $NIC = Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object {$_.DNSDomain -eq "contoso.com"} | Select-Object MACAddress, DNSHostName
        $NIC2 = {Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object {$_.DNSDomain -eq "contoso.com"} | Select-Object IPAddress} 
        $Value = $TESTConnection.PingSucceeded
        $PingAddress = $IPAddress.RemoteAddress

        
      }  
    Else {
     
        $Value          = $TESTConnection.PingSucceeded
        $PingAddress    = $IPAddress.RemoteAddress
        $NICIP         = "NOT REACHABLE"
    } 
# Create object 
$Object = New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{ 

        Computer_Target                  = $computer
        ONLINE                           = $Value
        IPAddress_PING                   = $PingAddress
        IPResolved                       = $NIC2.IPAddress
        NameResolved                     = $NIC.DNSHostName
        MACAddress                       = $NIC.MACAddress
               

}) 
  
# Add object to array
$DataArray += $Object

#Display object
}

If($DataArray)
{
#Output Array Data into a CSV File
$DataArray | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

#end of file

Comment: Please include the code with which you export to CSV

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-networkadapterconfiguration IPAddress *is* an array. A single network adapter can have multiple IP addresses. If you are sure there is ever only one, then use `$NIC2.IPAddress[0]`

Comment: Zett42 - 

Thank you for your response.  
I think I understand now.  So regardless of how many values it is still returning an Array.  That's why I get that result I get in the CSV.  While in the output it doesn't matter it is an array. 

By putting [0] at the end that will give me the first (and only) value.  Hmmm..  
Ok - I'll try that and let you know.

Comment: Hmm...  Well that didn't work.  
In fact, it seemed to return no values at all for the entire spreadsheet.

Comment: Edited my original comment to include the entire code.

Comment: `$NIC2 = { ... }` -- what is your intention using the curly brackets? When used like this, curly brackets define a scriptblock for *later* execution. That is propably not what you want. Remove the curly brackets and you should be good.

Comment: The Curly brackets was a typo.  It's not in the script and removing them doesn't give me what I want.  I either get an empty field or I get other stuff like System.Object[]
  or System.String[] or I get the 

Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object {$_.DNSDomain -eq "contoso.com"} | Select-Object IPAddress

Returned.

Comment: Finally figured it out.  I posted my Answer below.

Comment: Vada, always look at property and methods details/types, etc. before using them. It will save you unneeded frustration/headaches/errors. This is why `Set-StrictMode`, `Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer`, `Trace-Command` and `Pester` mockups exist. and leveraging them to their fullest will clarify your dev efforts. Define and cast variables in advance to not get surprised. This is detailed in the `Set-StrictMode` documentation.

Comment: Postanote - I did and as you can see I was using an Array to pull the information.  Why the heck do I need an Array to pull information from another Array is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I finally figured it out because I kept going around in circles and getting nowhere.

Thank you to Zett42 who led me in the right direction but I was still failing.

My first problem was that I hadn't identified $NIC2 as an Array which was part of my issue when trying $NIC2[0].  However, even after being Defined as an Array it still didn't work.

I then created another array and did this $NICIP = $NIC2.IPAddress and then output $NICIP[0] which works.  Not exactly sure why that works.

Here is the entire code

```
#Definitions of variables
#************************
    #Defines the location and name of the text file from where computers will be pulled
    $Computers = Get-Content "c:\Temp\computers.txt"  

    #Defines the variable and format for Date
    $Date = Get-date -UFormat %h_%d_%y_%H%M

    #Define the name of the files to output
    $OutputFile = "C:\Temp\Verify-Computer-$Date.csv" #All Computers On-Line Status will be provided in this file

  
    #Defines the Array where to put the data and the $Ping variable to store the IP address
    $DataArray = @()
    $Resolution = New-Object System.Object.NetworkInformation.Ping

#Define A Function that will test which computers are on-line and create files to use in the other function.
ForEach ($computer in $Computers) 
{

#Defining the variables
$TESTConnection = $null
$Object = $null
$Value = $null
$IPAddress = $null
$NameResolution = $null
$PingAddress = $null
$NIC = $null
$NIC2 = @()
$NICIP = @()



# Ping computer
$TESTConnection = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object PingSucceeded 

    #If connection is live Get IP address
    IF ($TESTConnection.PingSucceeded -eq "True") {

        $IPAddress = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $computer -InformationLevel "Detailed" | Select-Object RemoteAddress
        $NIC = Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object {$_.DNSDomain -eq "contoso.com"} | Select-Object MACAddress, DNSHostName
        $NIC2 = Get-WmiObject win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $computer | Where-Object {$_.DNSDomain -eq "contoso.com"} | Select-Object IPAddress
        $Value = $TESTConnection.PingSucceeded
        $PingAddress = $IPAddress.RemoteAddress

        $NICIP = $NIC2.IPAddress
      }  
    Else {
     
        $Value          = $TESTConnection.PingSucceeded
        $PingAddress    = "NOT REACHABLE"
        
    } 
# Create object 
$Object = New-Object PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{ 

        Computer_Target                  = $computer
        ONLINE                           = $Value
        IPAddress_PING                   = $PingAddress
        IPResolved1                      = $NICIP[0]
        NameResolved                     = $NIC.DNSHostName
        MACAddress                       = $NIC.MACAddress
               

}) 
  
# Add object to array
$DataArray += $Object

#Display object
}

If($DataArray)
{
#Output Array Data into a CSV File
$DataArray | Export-Csv -Path $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
}
#end of file
```